# How to Structure multiple completion providers

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension to provide completion for web-extension [api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index). Now the problem is that I have to register like a million completion providers which will trigger on different occasions, like some will trigger on `chrome.` some will on `chrome.tabs.` and some on `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.` and so on. I am new to writing VS Code extensions and the way I know to register providers is in `activate` method of `extension.ts`, which looks something like this right now.

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import chromeCompletionItemProvider from './chrome/chromeCompletionItemProvider';
import tabsCompletionItemProvider from './chrome/tabs/tabsCompletionItemProvider';
import accessibilityFeaturesCompletionItemProvider from './chrome/accessibilityFeatures/accessibilityFeaturesCompletionItemProvider';

const documentSelector = ['javascript', 'typescript', 'plaintext'];

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    let chromeProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(documentSelector, {
        provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken, context: vscode.CompletionContext) {
            const commitCharacterCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('chrome');
            commitCharacterCompletion.commitCharacters = ['.'];
            commitCharacterCompletion.documentation = new vscode.MarkdownString('Chrome provides extensions with many special-purpose APIs like `chrome.runtime` and `chrome.alarms`.');

            // return all completion items as array
            return [
                commitCharacterCompletion,
            ];
        }
    });

    const chromeItemsProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(documentSelector, chromeCompletionItemProvider, '.');

    const accessibilityFeaturesProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(documentSelector, accessibilityFeaturesCompletionItemProvider, '.');
    const tabsProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(documentSelector, tabsCompletionItemProvider, '.');
}
```

I got all the different providers in separate files and I register them in `activate` method. But if I have to keep registering them like this my activate method will be like a 1000 lines long. Is there some way I structure them a bit, e.g. Register all providers related to `tabs` in `tabsCompletionItemProvider.ts`.
My  `tabsCompletionItemProvider.ts` looks like this:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

import properties from './properties.json';
import methods from './methods.json';
import events from './events.json';

const tabsCompletionItemProvider = {
    provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position) {
        // get all text until the `position` and check if it reads `chrome.tabs.`
        // and iff so then complete if `log`, `warn`, and `error`
        let linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.substr(0, position.character);
        if (!linePrefix.endsWith('chrome.tabs.')) {
            return undefined;
        }

        const propertiesCompletionItems = properties.map(prop => new vscode.CompletionItem(prop.name, vscode.CompletionItemKind.Property));
        const methodsCompletionItems = methods.map(func => {
            const completionItem = new vscode.CompletionItem(func.name, vscode.CompletionItemKind.Method);
            completionItem.documentation = new vscode.MarkdownString(func.description);
            return completionItem;
        });
        const eventsCompletionItems = events.map(e => new vscode.CompletionItem(e.name, vscode.CompletionItemKind.Event));

        return [
            ...propertiesCompletionItems,
            ...methodsCompletionItems,
            ...eventsCompletionItems,
        ];
    }
};

export default tabsCompletionItemProvider;
```

Any suggestions on how to structure my project will be appreciated.